# Creating function with array input with desired coefficient and evaluate it

Tags: functions, function-construction, partitions, coefficients, symmetry

I had asked the same question before here [Creating a list of functions with desired coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293111/creating-a-list-of-functions-with-desired-coefficients)
but did not get the desired answer, may be I was not clear in my question.
I have defined this function to results some list of functions, however its not returning what I want

```
    d = 5;
    xs = Array[x,d];
    newF[xs_List] := (Sum[((i)*(#[[i]])^2), {i, 2, d}] - Exp[#[[1]]]) & /@ Partition[xs, d, 1, {1, 1}];
    newF[xs]
```

It results in

```
{-E^x[1] + 2 x[2]^2 + 3 x[3]^2 + 4 x[4]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[2] + 
5 x[1]^2 + 2 x[3]^2 + 3 x[4]^2 + 4 x[5]^2, -E^x[3] + 4 x[1]^2 + 
5 x[2]^2 + 2 x[4]^2 + 3 x[5]^2, -E^x[4] + 3 x[1]^2 + 4 x[2]^2 + 
5 x[3]^2 + 2 x[5]^2, -E^x[5] + 2 x[1]^2 + 3 x[2]^2 + 4 x[3]^2 + 
5 x[4]^2}
```

What I want this to return

```
{-E^x[1] + 2 x[2]^2 + 3 x[3]^2 + 4 x[4]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[2] + 
x[1]^2 + 3 x[3]^2 + 4 x[4]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[3] + x[1]^2 + 
2 x[2]^2 + 4 x[4]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[4] + x[1]^2 + 2 x[2]^2 + 
3 x[3]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[5] + x[1]^2 + 2 x[2]^2 + 3 x[3]^2 + 
4 x[4]^2}
```

Basically I want is $-e^{x_k}+\sum_{n\neq k}n\cdot x_n^2$

The input should be that array $xs.$ I want it for different values of 'd'.

Further I should be able to evaluate it at an array like $(1,1,1,1,1)$ or $(1,2,3,4,5).$ I mean is I can define

```
 ys = ConstantArray[1/10, d];
```

and evaluate

```
newF[ys]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

g[d_Integer] := Module[{
   r = Range[d]
   , f = -Exp[x[First@#]] + Total[# x[#]^2 & /@ Last@#] &
   },
   t = TakeList[Range[d], {{#}, All}] & /@ r // Map[FlattenAt[1]];
  f /@ t
  ]
```

---

*Usage:*

```
g[5]
```

> {-E^x[1] + 2 x[2]^2 + 3 x[3]^2 + 4 x[4]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[2] +
> x[1]^2 + 3 x[3]^2 + 4 x[4]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[3] + x[1]^2 +    2
> x[2]^2 + 4 x[4]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[4] + x[1]^2 + 2 x[2]^2 +    3
> x[3]^2 + 5 x[5]^2, -E^x[5] + x[1]^2 + 2 x[2]^2 + 3 x[3]^2 +    4
> x[4]^2}

---

*EDIT*

To evaluate:

```
g[5] /. Thread[Array[x, 5] -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

> {224 - E, 217 - E^2, 198 - E^3, 161 - E^4, 100 - E^5}